# HTML5 video tag with https source

Tags: html, video, https, html5-video

Is it possible to play a video via the HTML5 video tag using HTTPS as the video source? Our page is entirely in HTTPS, however when you browse we are getting the mixed http/https mode message. The video configured to use HTTPS as the source is changing to HTTP somehow. We don't see any 302 redirects coming from the web server. Is this browser dependent? We've tried all possible browsers. Code snipplet below from the developer tool output.

```
<video id="homepageCenterVideo_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" data-setup="{}" poster="/CMSImages/static_image.jpg" src="https://www.domain.com/Video/Makes_It_Easy.mp4" controls="">
    <source src="https://www.domain.com/Video/Makes_It_Easy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you were to copy that URI and paste it into the URL bar, you can see that it changes from https to http and we still don't see any 302 redirects coming from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got the HTML5 video to work using HTTPS, however we still don't know why. The back-end server is IIS. The directory housing the video file is named "video". If we change the name of that directory, or put the video file in another directory it's able to stream using HTTPS just fine. If we rename the directory back to "video" it won't work and uses HTTP. Very weird, but we're assuming it has something to do with IIS settings somewhere.